Preserving Markdown Styling in XLSX Generation
I am attempting to generate an XLSX file from a JSON object, where one of the fields contains Markdown text. While generating the XLSX file, I want to preserve the styling present in the Markdown text. I've tried using the xlsx module, but I haven't been successful in retaining the styling.
const data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        markdownField: "Testing **How** to format the *data* \n1. Point 1\n2. Point 2"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        markdownField: "Another **example** of *Markdown* text \n- Item 1\n- Item 2"
    }
];

const XLSX = require('xlsx');

const ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data);

const wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Data');

XLSX.writeFile(wb, 'output.xlsx');

In the resulting XLSX file, the Markdown styling (e.g., bold, italic, list) is not retained. How can I preserve the Markdown styling when generating the XLSX file?
Also, I tried to convert markdown text to HTML and then generate xlsx but still no luck, Here is the generated html
Testing <strong>How</strong> to format the <em>data</em><ol><li>Point 1</li><li>Point 2</li></ol>

